# How do you sort an XDocument parent node based its child?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

In C# I am trying to sort an `XDocument` using `OrderByDescending`. The goal is to read one of the child nodes which contains a date/time stamp and reorder the parent nodes.

I load the XML from a saved file like this:

```
XDocument Doc = new XDocument();
Doc= XDocument.Load(filename);
```

Here is an example of my XML:

```
<KS>
  <Team>   
    <TeamName>Knights</TeamName>
    <TeamColor>blue</TeamColor>
    <LastAccessed>5/9/2013 2:34:22 PM</LastAccessed>
  </Team>
  <Team>
    <TeamName>Rangers</TeamName>
    <TeamColor>red</TeamColor>
    <LastAccessed>5/9/2013 3:49:06 PM</LastAccessed>
  </Team>
  <Team>
    <TeamName>Eagles</TeamName>
    <TeamColor>green</TeamColor>    
    <LastAccessed>5/9/2013 3:50:18 PM</LastAccessed>
  </Team>
</KS>
```

I would like to reorder `<Team>` descending based on the child element `<LastAccessed>`.

I have tried the following without any luck:

```
var results = Doc.Root.Descendants("Team").OrderByDescending(p => p.Element("LastAccessed"));

XDocument node = new XDocument(Doc.Descendants("KS").OrderByDescending(x => x.Element("Team").Element("LastAccessed").Value.Trim()));
```

Any suggestions how one would sort XML parent nodes based on a value stored in the child node?

Comment: What datetime format are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should have gotten an error that said:

> At least one object must implement IComparable.

Please always **include** these errors in your questions.

You need to provide a child of the `Team` element that supports the [IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx) interface. You need to get the value rather than the `XElement` that [`.Elements`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.element.aspx) gives you.

Change your results line to the below and it will work.

```
var results = Doc.Descendants("Team").OrderByDescending(p => DateTime.Parse(p.Element("LastAccessed").Value));
```

Comment: So `15/9/2013 3:50:18 PM` comes after `5/9/2013 3:50:18 PM` in descending order?

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = Doc.Root.Descendants("Team").OrderByDescending(p =>    (DateTime)p.Element("LastAccessed"));
```